# Is there an equivalent to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate in C#/UWP?

Tags: c#, image, uwp

One of the handiest things about working with images in iOS is the ability to treat the image as a transparency mask (looking only at the alpha channel) and recolor the image using a tint color, allowing a single image resource to be used to generate a solid color glyph in any color dynamically at runtime.

I'm just wondering if there is any similar such ability in C# (preferably without third-party code) on the UWP platform, or if I'm better off just doing this in Photoshop and saving a new resource.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just wondering if there is any similar such ability in C# (preferably without third-party code) on the UWP platform, or if I'm better off just doing this in Photoshop and saving a new resource.

Not familiar with iOS development, after googling I think, there is no such API avaiable in UWP AFAIK, but [Microsoft Lumia SDKs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/featured/lumia) can make it easier although you prefer not using third-party code.

If you're interest in this [package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598502.aspx), here is some information. You can use [ColorAdjustEffect Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.adjustments.coloradjusteffect.aspx) to adjust the RGB color composition of the image by setting `ColorAdjustEffect.Blue`, `ColorAdjustEffect.Green` and `ColorAdjustEffect.Red`. The range of these properties is from -1.0 to 1.0. Also you can set the Color.R as a value between 0 and 255.

Doing this in Photoshop and saving a new resource is also a method since there is no standard API which can directly do this work in UWP.